Is there a measure that produces given values (probabilities or cardinals) for sets $A_1,\dots, A_n$ and all their intersections $A_i\cap A_j, ... $?
Assume that values (e.g., probabilities or cardinals) of a measure on a finite set $\Omega$  are given for sets $A_1,\dots, A_n$ and all of their intersections $A_i, A_i\cap A_j, A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k, ...$. My question:

Is there any necessary and sufficient condition that can be simply checked to make sure that there is a measure on the set $\Omega$ that can produce the given numbers.

I came across this problem after solving this counting question, where I realized the numbers given in the source textbook cannot be correct, and showed it by checking two sufficient conditions.
I am wondering if there is any efficient algorithm for this purpose. I guess the above problem should be NP-hard since I can formulate it as a linear programming model for the case of real-valued measures (such as probability measures), which includes exponential number $O(2^n)$ of linear constraints involving $|\Omega|$ variables. I think the problem is more difficult for integer-valued measures.

As stated, you have $2^n-1$ values whose consistency you want to check so you are not going to be more efficient than that.

Hope a more efficient method is presented with better average performance.

You might be able to spot an inconsistency faster than that if you are lucky: for example being told $\mu(A_1)=0.3$ and $\mu(A_1 \cap A_2)=0.7$ $($and $\mu(A_2)=0.9)$ only requires a comparison of two values, but showing consistency requires looking at all the values so cannot be any faster.

Yes exactly! It is why I told better average performance in my comment. Some type of polyhedral analysis may be useful; see e.g., the method used in this answer.

@Henry Let $N = 2^n - 1$ be the size of the input. The desired algorithm cannot be faster than $O(N)$, agreed. But can it actually be achieved?

@Amir, can you describe any algorithm to check the consistency and its asymptotic complexity?

@paperskilltrees as stated in the OP, the only method I currently know is to find a feasible solution to a system involving $O(2^n)$ linear equations and $|\Omega|$ variables.
